# How to change an email's received "sender" field to another name? If possible in GMAIL

Tags: email, gmail, windows-live-mail

Is it possible when I send and receive email that someone has it's name identified as another name? Is there any better option for doing that? I use Windows Live Mail, receiving from my GMAIL account, so is it better to make it work in which one?

Answer (score 0):

Most modern email clients have some sort of "Contacts" feature that allow you to create a profile to associate with a particular email address. In Gmail, creating a contact profile for an email address effectively allows you to display a name of your choosing next to the email address should it appear in any `To`, `CC`, `BCC`, `From`, `Sender`, etc. field.

For example, were you to add the email address `georgypoo@yahoo.com` to your contacts and assign it the name `George Foreman`, whenever `georgypoo@yahoo.com` sent you a message, the message's `Sender` or `From` field would display `George Foreman <georgypoo@yahoo.com>`.

However, as you are using Windows Live Mail to check your Gmail account and all of your contact information would reside solely in Gmail, you must instead create your contact profiles in the Windows Live Mail application, and not in Gmail.

I hope I haven't misinterpreted your question

Comment: No you are right, but it seems that only the first email gets the saved "contact" name, the other go back to the persons original email sender name. Now what?